# 'switch'/'case' for determining the variable to assign to in Python

Tags: python, switch-statement

I'd like to use a "switch/case" structure to decide which variable to assign a value to based on some parameter:

```
a, b = [init_val] * 2
# This doesn't exist in Python.
switch param
    case 'a':
        a = final_val
    case 'b':
        b = final_val
```

The dictionary method described in the question *[Replacements for switch statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python/103081#103081)* doesn't work here, since you can neither assign to a function call,

```
a, b = [init_val] * 2
switcher = {
    'a': a,
    'b': b
}
switcher.get(param) = final_val
```

nor change the value of a variable by storing it in a dictionary:

```
switcher[param] = final_val  # switcher['a'] is only a copy of variable a
```

I could just stick to "if/elif", but since I have often seen that nice dictionary solution (as in the aforementioned question) for determining an output based on some parameter, I'm curious to see if there's a similar solution for determining which variable, out of a set of variables, to assign a value to.

Comment: You could always just do `switcher[param] = final_val`

Comment: Don't use a bunch of variables, use *a container, like a dictionary*.

Comment: Just use a dict.

Comment: @COLDSPEED That does not modify the value of the variable, only the dictionary element.

Comment: Anyway, you can dynamically assign to a global variable rather easily in Python: `globals()[switcher.get(param)] = final_val`, however, this is hackey, and *really* suggests that your "variables" should just be keys in their own dictionary, instead of clobbering the *globals dictionary*. Dynamically assigning to local variables is tougher in Python, and will be version / implementation dependent. Python 3 has made this a lot harder. Just don't do it. I hesitate to say "never", but I've never seen a good reason to.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, so instead of `return a, b`, I would end up with `return var_dict['a'], var_dict['b']`?

Comment: @NathanielJones sure. Although, unless you have a bunch of variables, a simple if-else is probably fine in this case. No need to go around over-engineering things. Code is written once, but read many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Comment: @Skandix I have just edited my question. I think it's slightly different than the one you mention. However, I am new to StackOverflow: Would this have worked better as a comment on that question?

Comment: @StephenRauch  A `dict` requires a single value lookup: it misses out on conditional expressions for selection of the appropriate assignment. Just a big miss in python.

Comment: @javadb, big miss?  What language and structure do feel is so superior in this regard?

Comment: look up `match/case` in _scala. Or any other language that supports assignment from arbitrary statements.

Comment: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html    But you can assign _anything_ to a variable in scala: the point is that arbitrary statements or generators including conditional ones can produce a result that is assigned to a variable. I keep coming back to this and _hoping_/wishing python had something a little less awkward then explicitly assigning the output variable for every conditional branch. It also means setting the variable to `None` in a separate (/awkward) line by itself

Comment: Well I will have to respectable disagree that scala's match/case is somehow a so much better solution to the listed question that somehow this is a "big miss" in Python.  Cheers.

Comment: I think you missed the actual question which is trying to assign to "different" variables based on a question.

Comment: [Python 3.10 (2021) has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python/60211#60211).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python, in general, does not have a built-in switch/case functionality. Instead, common practice is to use the `elif` keyword as such:

```
a, b = [init_val] * 2
if param == 'a':
    a = final_val
elif param == 'b':
    b = final_val
else:
    pass # or do something else
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the repetitive `elif param == `, but so far this seems like the way to go, and not much different from a switch/case (in fact, it involves less indentation).

Comment: @javadba Python has many advantages and many disadvantages, so does any other programming language. Claiming it is weak due to a single (lack of) feature is not very professional...

Comment: @JimmyLeeJones  I can go into much more serious issues  with python :  this is a relatively smaller one .   My preference would be to hear: "oh you can get around it this way or that way".  Then i'd remove the comment. I _do_ use the language: there is no `numpy` or `tensorflow` or `opencv` in `scala` or `ruby`.

Comment: [Python 3.10 (2021) has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python/60211#60211).

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.10 (2021), you can avail the [`match`-`case`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0634/) construct.

```py
a, b = [init_val] * 2

# This exists in Python 3.10+
match param:
    case 'a':
        a = final_val
    case 'b':
        b = final_val
```